# BackgroundWorker with a Recursive Function

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, recursion, backgroundworker

I have a pretty good grasp on how to use the [System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx), basically you have a single "DoWork" function and usually some loop that does work and each iteration you check `e.Cancel` to determine whether or not to break and stop the loop to end the `BackgroundWorker`'s "DoWork" (this all assumes the `WorkerSupportsCancellation` property is set correctly to `true`).

What I'm not sure about is if I have a recursive function (the exact function doesn't matter, any recursive function let's say the classic compute factorials) that performs my task (rather than a loop) how can I call this from inside a "DoWork" function, and how do I propagate up the `e.Cancel` up in this case to bail out on the recursion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean something like this? As soon as the cancel is initiated the recursive loop will unroll till the top and you are stopped.

```
void RecursiveLoop(BackGroundWorker worker)
{
  // ON entry check if we need to stop
  if (worker.CancellationPending) return;
  //
  // Normal code and the recursion
  if (morework) RecursiveLoop(worker);
}
```

Comment: Cool thanks, passing up the `BackGroundWorker` is definitely a quick way to do this, esp. if I want to report some type of progress inside the recursion as well.  Though, not sure Erno's may be more efficient?

Comment: Not sure why you would go the delegate route. As you pass the delegates just like the bgworker I also do not see more efficiency.

Comment: I think this answer makes the most sense to me.

Comment: The reason to use the delegate is to keep a clean separation between two functionalities: the work (the function) and the management of execution (the background worker) Imagine the changes you would need to make to the code when you decide to use a Task instead of the background worker.

Comment: Those changes are minor and easily done . I try to stay away from extra complexity for the sake of possible future changes. But that would indeed be a reason for a delegate setup.

Answer (score 2):

Create a delegate to function that cancels the background worker.

Create a delegate to function that returns false when cancellation for the background worker is pending.

Pass these delegates to the recursive function and make sure it passes these delegates to each recursive call.

In the recursive function call the first delegate when you want to cancel the background worker.

Finally, in the recursive function check for a pending cancellation using the second delegate.

This way you do not have to pass the background worker around.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered writing an unrolled recursive while loop?  The advantages of an "unrolled recusive loop" are:

- The Stack<> object can use up all available memory, but won't result in a stackoverflow
- The function call can be canceled with one test and return, no matter how deep the work queue was
- You can report progress on it, if you like (e.g. progress percentage = num_items_processed / stack size + num_items_processed)
- You can pause the execution anytime you want and resume it later

Here's one potential implementation of an unrolled recursion:

```
void RecursiveLoop(WorkItem item)
{
    // Create a stack and push our item onto it
    Stack<WorkItem> recursion = new Stack<WorkItem>();
    recursion.Push(item);

    // Loop through all items in the stack
    while ((!cancel_flag_set) && (recursion.Count > 0)) {
        WorkItem current = recursion.Pop();

        // ... Do Work Here ...

        // Now, queue up all the child items
        foreach (WorkItem child in current.ChildItems) {
            recursion.Push(child);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check `e.Cancel` at the start of the function and, if it is true, set a member variable in the class scope.  Use that variable to determine whether to continue or not.